# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - December 2017

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the third edition of the Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

This report will be published Monthly / Quarterly / Yearly. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for December 2017

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Close Votes Reviewed Award
6. Most First Posts Reviewed Award
7. Most Late Answers Reviewed Award
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award
9. Most Reopen Reviews Award
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                    SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      370
2   Monomeeth                  270
3   patrix                     230
4   JMY1000                    170
5   grgarside                  130
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 650.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]

You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/46/month/apple/2017-12-01).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    107
2   bmike                     95
3   patrix                    93
4   grgarside                 88
5   klanomath                 87
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                    809
2   Monomeeth                 600
3   LangLangC                 259
4   Citizen                   221
5   JW8                       212
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST CLOSE VOTES REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   patrix                    75
2   Allan                     57
3   fsb                       44
4   pjc90                     29
5   Mark                      22
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST FIRST POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   JMY1000                  232
2   patrix                   181
3   Allan                    116
4   fsb                       64
5   Jackson1442               49
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LATE ANSWERS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     87
2   JMY1000                   65
3   Glorfindel                33
4   Scot                      22
5   LangLangC                 20
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LOW-QUALITY POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   JMY1000                   65
2   Allan                     42
3   fsb                       26
4   Tetsujin                  23
5   Scot                      19
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST REOPEN POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    16
2   patrix                   14
3   Tetsujin, fsb, pjc90      5
4   Glorfindel, Mark          4   
5   grgarside, Monomeeth, 
    IconDaemon, bjbk          2
```

---

[image: TITLE: MOST SUGGESTED EDITS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   techraf                  79
2   Allan                    32
3   patrix, JMY1000          27
4   Glorfindel               16
5   grgarside                13
```

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Is there a native QR Code reader on iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310390/is-there-a-native-qr-code-reader-on-iphone)

   - Posted by: user269696
   - Votes: **30**
2. [Is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate one level up in Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307930/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-navigate-one-level-up-in-finder)

   - Posted by: user674669
   - Votes: **22**
3. [Is it safe to let apps use Touch ID on an iOS device?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309093/is-it-safe-to-let-apps-use-touch-id-on-an-ios-device)

   - Posted by: Oleksandr Shpota
   - Votes: **19**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

**1st.** [Is there a native QR Code reader on iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310390/is-there-a-native-qr-code-reader-on-iphone/310392#310392)

- Answered by: Monomeeth
- Votes: **42**

**2nd.** [Is it possible to use my Mac to mine Bitcoins?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308865/is-it-possible-to-use-my-mac-to-mine-bitcoins/308868#308868)

- Answered by: Monomeeth
- Votes: **39**

**3rd.** [Is it safe to let apps use Touch ID on an iOS device?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309093/is-it-safe-to-let-apps-use-touch-id-on-an-ios-device/309098#309098)

- Answered by: Mateusz Szlosek
- Votes: **38**

**3rd.** [Is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate one level up in Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307930/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-navigate-one-level-up-in-finder/307934#307934)

- Answered by: Monomeeth
- Votes: **38**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Month 13 is out of bounds?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/307512/168832)

   - Posted by: nobody user
   - Views: **16,846**
2. [Is it possible to use my Mac to mine Bitcoins?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308865/is-it-possible-to-use-my-mac-to-mine-bitcoins)

   - Posted by: LJH
   - Views: **6,600**
3. [What is rapportd and why does it want incoming network connections?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/308294/168832)

   - Posted by: Dave
   - Views: **6,289**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Close Votes Reviewed Award**

- [patrix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/patrix)

**6.    Most First Posts Reviewed Award**

- [JMY1000](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/140612/jmy1000)

**7.    Most Late Answers Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**8.    Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award**

- [JMY1000](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/140612/jmy1000)

**9.    Most Reopen Reviews Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award**

- [Techraf](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/145449/techraf)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [user269696](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/269696/user269696)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [nobody user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/264298/nobody-user)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In December our [Moderators](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned 427 flags with an average handling time of 15 minutes. In summary, we:

- deleted 289 comments
- deleted 291 posts
- closed 212 posts
- edited 268 posts
- created 159 posts
- created 416 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)

Comment: Thank you for your work!

Comment: Monomeeth is awesome