# Most Active Contributors Discontinued?

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors

I haven't seen the Most Active Contributors monthly report since [Dec 2018](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3185/most-active-contributors-monthly-report-december-2017).  I find the info very interesting and informative (h/t @Monomeeth).

Has that been discontinued?  It looks like it takes a lot of time to put together and I was just wondering what happened to it.

Comment: It is a purely volunteer effort - let’s see if our volunteer was away or needs help to organize it.

Comment: @bmike Thanks.  I know Monomeeth has been doing it for a long time and I appreciate the efforts. It would be great if someone could automate the creation of this (it's beyond my skill level).

Comment: I think I saw in chat (or an old meta post I’m not seeing right now) that monomeeth was both busy in January and working on a yearly contributor post that was taking longer than usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted from Ask Different chat:

> Apologies for the delay, had some major real-life distractions for the past couple of weeks. All the data is ready, but I've actually been working on the first annual edition (taking more time since it's the first one, so no existing templates, images, etc). I guess I could publish the January monthly report first if people were keen. Regardless, will be back to the usual schedule by the time the February report needs to go out.

Comment: Great!  Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the slightly delayed, but very much completed January 2019 edition of the report.

- [Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - January 2019](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/most-active-contributors-monthly-report-january-2019)